# Puzzle game with multiple levels. What should I use ? Layers or Scenes ? And why?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, layer, scene

I've created a simple puzzle game, where I have to load a new layer of puzzle pieces after the first level is done. How do I manage that ? Do I have to create a class for each scene, or can I implement it straight away in the class where the scene of level 1 exists ? If yes, how do i do that ? Or is it more convenient to make different layers for the levels ? And if you could give me a small example of how to switch to another layer, I would be very thankful. Currently, I have a menu class and a Game class. When you click the "Start game" button in the menu, it will take you to the game scene, which is in the Game class. Where do I put next layers/scenes ? I hope my points are clear, if not please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you managed you create your puzzle game's first level and now you're unsure about "going to the next level"?

You don't need to make a new class per stage. One class is enough.

Your Game class should be able to read some data and interpret it to build the stage. An interesting method would be having a .plist file in your project containing the necessary data for every level of the game. The .plist file is a Dictionary. You can make a key representing the first level (1) and another key representing the second level (2) and so on. The value for each key would be another dictionary with further data: A key for the number of monsters in the level: (monsters), a key for the time limit in the level, etc..........

The point is, it is wasteful to create a whole new class for every level you got. As long as one, main class can interpret a certain source of information and build it, it will be enough.

Anyway, if you were wondering about transferring between CCScenes, here's an useful link: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_3._menus_and_scenes

Comment: Yes I did manage to build this game. I am pretty new to obj-c (and I haven't got knowledge of other major object oriented programming languages) but I am working very hard on it and I am proud to say that I have grasped a significant amount of the language by doing it. Anyway, thanks for your response. I did know how to transfer between Scenes, but I just found it a little bit strange that there has to be a separate class for each level. I did not know how to handle this problem. I have no clue how to use the plist file either, as easy as it may sound, but at least I have already heard aboutit

Comment: So what exactly do you need to know now?

Comment: I wanted to know what is most efficient/convenient for building a level game. I heard about doing it with plist files, and I've also seen a game where they used multiple classes which seems a little bit inconvenient to tackle this problem. How would games like "Cut the Rope" do it ?

Comment: If you are taking Cut the Rope as an example or almost any other game like Angry Birds etc, I bet they simply use .plist files (or a similar info source) as I told you. What you truly need to know is how to read .plist files so that your one class can build the level. Making 100+ classes representing the game's stages is not a good choice.

Comment: In Angry Birds for example, I bet that one .plist file of them has keys like the following: "Array of birds", "Array of pigs and positions", "Array of obstacles and positions", etc. Perhaps one .plist per stage (or just one .plist containing all stages. Whatever works).

Comment: Okay cool. So a .plist file should be fine to use to store level data ?

Comment: Yes. .plist files provide info. All you have to do is interpret it properly, saving you lots of time.